# Best practices for generating unique multi-column keys for weak entities?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, auto-increment

How should one generate non-unique, non-natural identifiers for weak entities?

For example, if `order_id` is the primary key for an `order` table, and `(order_id, item_number)` is the primary key for an `order_item` table with a foreign key on `order_id`, how best to generate `item_number`?

A few of possibilities come to mind, but none seem ideal:

1. Autoincrement `item_number`: the `order_item` entity is no longer weak, and the composite key is redundant.
2. Use a trigger to search for the current max `item_number` for a given `order_id`, then increment: if a row is deleted this could lead to reassigning a PK to a different record - that doesn't seem like a good idea? *(edit: this can also be done without using triggers as explained in [joanolo's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161080/best-practices-for-generating-unique-multi-column-keys-for-weak-entities/161089#161089))*
3. Use a trigger to create a new sequence for every `order_id`, and somehow draw `item_number`s from the appropriate sequence: this is functionally the desired behaviour, but seems like it would be a mess to implement. Is it even possible to reference a sequence by an `order_id`?

*Edit - closely related (if not duplicate):*

- [Create unique sequence per set of rows sharing the same foreign key value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135437/create-unique-sequence-per-set-of-rows-sharing-the-same-foreign-key-value)
- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key)

Comment: I think I'd change the title to something like generating *unique* multi-column keys instead of *non-unique*. Because you're actually looking for a PK.

Comment: Good point - I've changed the title accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1.*** is the least error-prone, simplest and fastest.
Trigger solutions like in ***2.*** or ***3.*** are subject to subtle race conditions under concurrent write access.

Make `item_number` a `serial` column and also the PK for `order_item` in this case. Stick with the default values drawn from the underlying sequence and *never* update the column.

- [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

Create a multi-column index on `(order_id, item_number)` for performance of typical queries. (Might as well be `UNIQUE`, but does not have to be.) In a typical setup (`order_id` and `item_number` can both be plain `integer`), the multicolumn index happens to be just as small and fast as an index on just `order_id`:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

(Like I commented:) Typically, the only important role of an item number is to be *unique* (and *immutable*). If you need a *stable* sort order among items, you might just rely on the serial value of `item_number`. Be aware that those numbers are not necessarily in order of transaction commits. It may be useful to add the transaction timestamp [`current_timestamp` (or possibly `statement_timestamp()` or `clock_timestamp()`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) to the row. Depends on requirements and access patterns.

You can add a `VIEW` for the human eye, with item-numbers per `order_id` starting from *1*, dynamically generated with [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html), ordered by above criteria. But operate with the unique, immutable `item_number` internally.

- [Create unique sequence per set of rows sharing the same foreign key value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135437/create-unique-sequence-per-set-of-rows-sharing-the-same-foreign-key-value/135446#135446)

Comment: Thanks, I imagine I'll end up taking this route. With the composite key I had hoped to get an elegant way to hide the total `order_item` table size in my application's API - but I'll just have to do that more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a fourth alternative, that is consistent with your definition, where the database takes care of itemNumbers when you `INSERT` your data; without the need for triggers. [Although you could use them as well.]

Assuming this is your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "Order"
(
    "orderId" integer primary key,  -- this should probably be serial
    "order" text not null
) ;

CREATE TABLE "OrderItem"
(
    "orderId" integer not null REFERENCES "Order"("orderId") 
         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    "itemNumber" integer not null,
    "orderItem" text,

    PRIMARY KEY ("orderId", "itemNumber")
) ;
```

and that we have three orders:

```
INSERT INTO "Order" ("orderId", "order") VALUES(1, 'Order number 1') ;
INSERT INTO "Order" ("orderId", "order") VALUES(2, 'Order number 2') ;
INSERT INTO "Order" ("orderId", "order") VALUES(3, 'Order number 3') ;
```

If you need to add ONE item to order 3, you'd do:

```
INSERT INTO 
    "OrderItem" 
    ("orderId", "orderItem", "itemNumber")
VALUES 
    (3, 'whichever item you need', 
     (SELECT coalesce(max("itemNumber"),0) + 1 
        FROM "OrderItem" 
       WHERE "orderId"=3)
    ) ;
```

That is, when you `INSERT`, you just look for the `max("itemNumber")` *for your specific "order_Id"* and add 1 to it. If this is the first item you insert an item to an order, the COALESCE(___, 0) + 1 will give you a 0 + 1, instead of NULL + 1 (which wouldn't work).

If you need to add several items to several orders (which isn't that common for most applications), you can do it in a slightly more complicated fashion, but using the same principle:

```
-- Assume you want to add items to orders 1 and 2
WITH "orderItemsToAdd" ("orderId", "orderItem") AS
(
    VALUES 
    (1, 'first item, 1st order'), 
    (1, 'second item, 1st order'),
    (2, 'first item, 2nd order'),
    (2, 'second item, 2nd order'),
    (2, 'third item, 2nd order')
)

-- Get the max item numbers (or zero, via coalesce) for each order

, "maxItemNumbers" AS
(
SELECT
    "orderId", coalesce(max("itemNumber"), 0) AS "baseItemNumber"
FROM
    "orderItemsToAdd"
    LEFT JOIN "OrderItem" USING("orderId")
GROUP BY
    "orderId"                    
)

-- We insert new items, using row_number() + baseItemNumber as the new item numbers
-- (NOTE: orderItemsToAdd should, in practice be ORDERed BY something!)
INSERT INTO 
    "OrderItem" ("orderId", "itemNumber", "orderItem")
SELECT
    "orderId", "baseItemNumber" + (row_number() over (partition by "orderId")), "orderItem"
FROM
    "orderItemsToAdd" 
    JOIN "maxItemNumbers" USING("orderId")
RETURNING
    * ;
```

This is what you'll get:

```
    +--------------------------------+
    ¦ 1 ¦ 1 ¦ first item, 1st order  ¦
    ¦---+---+------------------------¦
    ¦ 1 ¦ 2 ¦ second item, 1st order ¦
    ¦---+---+------------------------¦
    ¦ 2 ¦ 1 ¦ first item, 2nd order  ¦
    ¦---+---+------------------------¦
    ¦ 2 ¦ 2 ¦ second item, 2nd order ¦
    ¦---+---+------------------------¦
    ¦ 2 ¦ 3 ¦ third item, 2nd order  ¦
    +--------------------------------+
```

You can check it at [rextester](http://rextester.com/TWNQ5981).

You need to be aware of:

- [row_number()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) window function
- [Window function calls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)
- [Window Function Processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW)

---

As a side note, if you use PostgreSQL, I'd advise using `underscored_lowercase_identifiers` instead of `camelCaseOnes`. You save a lot of time not having to type `"` (and the risk of forgetting them) ;-)

---

Second side-note: this approach can lead to race conditions (and transactions having to be aborted then retried) if *many* people try to change the *same order* at the *same time*. See comments by @Erwin.

Comment: How to deal with inherent race conditions under concurrent write load? How to guarantee that the suggested statements are the only ones writing to the tables? How to deal with (concurrent?) `DELETE` or `UPDATE` and with resulting gaps in the item numbers? Can gap-less item numbers be guaranteed? (Typically, no.)

Comment: Gap-less item numbers are not guaranteed. If that's not an option, this approach is not good enough, agreed. You can have race conditions: if they happen, your transaction aborts, and probably needs to be retried. This is, for me, an uncommon scenario for order entry (several people adding items to the *same* order at the *same* time). It is a problem *in general*.

Comment: Own experiences says it's easier to deal with itemNumbers 1, 3, 4, 5 (you know line 2 existed once, although maybe only for 10 seconds) than to have itemNumbers 1000, 1327, 1456, 1793, which tell you next to nothing. A row_number() on a view *hides* this information.  I know you can also have *auditing* or *journaling*, in case full history needs to be retained, but this is somewhere in the middle. Like always, *best* depends on the *use-case*. I'm shooting for what I'd consider *common*.

Comment: Typically, the *only* important role of an item number is to be unique. To establish a sort order, add the transaction timestamp (or possibly [`statement_timestamp()` or `clock_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)). I would only even consider numbering from 1 per order in trivial cases without concurrent write access and no possible complications. And I would certainly put the logic into *triggers* in such a case. Else, there is no guarantee the rules are enforced at all times, and the whole setup remains unreliable.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't familiar with window functions so didn't know this could be an option. Ultimately though, I think I'd rather keep the key generation logic in the database, instead of depending on applications to use specific queries.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: That might be differences in *naming conventions*... but if this were the case, I wouldn't call it an *Item Number* but an *Item Id*.

Comment: @joanolo: You got a point there.